# VS Code and C# - Double quote followed by an underscore

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I've been having this problem in VS Code and C# where if I had a double quote followed by an underscore, like the string `"_something"`, the syntax highlighting below that line gets ruined.

Here is an example:

[image: Commented]

[image: Uncommented]

When the offending line is commented out, the syntax highlighting works as expected. But when uncommented, the syntax highlighting gets ruined. In this case, the string starts with two underscores, but this also happens with only one underscore. How do I go about fixing this setting in VS Code?

The plugin I'm using for the theme is the Material Theme with default settings, although it doesn't seem to matter which theme is used. Thanks!

Comment: Are you expecting to fix it by writing code? If not, this should be a bug report.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a programming question.

Comment: @madreflection Well, I'm hoping to fix it through some plugin settings in the Material Theme, although I doubt it only applies to that theme since I've tried some other themes and they all do the same thing. I'm just not sure why VS Code sees the `"_` character combination as something different for C#, or if there even is a name for such a syntax. I'm not sure where exactly to post questions about VS Code settings either. And if I can't post those questions here, what exactly is the `visual-studio-code` tag for?

Comment: That's fine, but it still wouldn't be a programming question. That tag is for questions about developing plugins for VS Code and problems related to that code.

Comment: @madreflection Briefly looking over the posts under the tag `visual-studio-code`, most of them ask about what settings to change in their VS Code or plugins they **installed** to fix something about their own VS Code editor. I can't even find any posts asking about problems about **developing/programming** their plugins for VS Code. The tag itself also doesn't specify that it's only meant for when programming plugins for VS Code.

Comment: I'll stand corrected on that point. I still think this is a bug report, though. It looks like the syntax highlighter just doesn't know how to interpret that character sequence (and it *shouldn't* be interpreting the contents of a simple string at all).

Comment: @madreflection Alright, thanks for your input and for being understanding. I'll be submitting an issue on VS Code's Github page for this, since it doesn't seem to be intended.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there was a different plugin causing the problem, linked below:

[Identical Sublime Monokai C# theme and colorizer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=maximetinu.identical-sublime-monokai-csharp-theme-colorizer)

The syntax highlighting still exhibits the problem mentioned above even when only this plugin was enabled, therefore the problem is caused solely by the plugin and not due to conflicting plugins. I'll now be reporting this issue on the plugin's repo.